# Deny Access for Browser to upload or open system Files

Tags: google-chrome, browser, kernel, minifilter

I and My team are working on a project where our main task is to block the browser or particular website to have upload access. For eg, if we go to Facebook and want to upload a new profile picture, the Fb website allow us to open our system directory and traverse through our system file. We want to prevent this access of uploading files on websites.

My friend suggested that it can be done using **Windows Driver**. I have a basic knowledge of C++, registry, and service API functions. My queries..

1. Is there any other way to block these upload access by browser?
2. If Windows Driver can do it, then what should I learn and where to start?
3. Is it possible using a Storage driver or file system driver?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a File System Filter Drivers, which allows you to block some access to files.

I would start in Microsoft Documentation [File System Filter Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/introduction-to-file-system-filter-drivers). also, I would recommend reading ["Windows Kernel Programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1977593372) book by Pavel Yosifovich, it has a couple of chapters on that topic.

Comment: Hey Baget! Thank you for your advice. Now I can able to block a particular file(eg: notepad text file) from opening. But now I want to block file access which was invoked by a browser or a particular URL.

Comment: Drivers are not aware of process special data, URL is processed special address. you need to use the browser API or other techniques to get this information (getting Control data from HWND) but it is more complex